How to create a pty with pipes on both ends
I am attempting to use minimodem to connect 2 computers over audible sound (ik it's weird but I like shenanigans). minimodem uses pipes, either into it for transmit, or out for recieve. I would like to treat this connection like a serial connection for a remote terminal. i've read this is possible with socat but I'm struggling to figure out how
